# Nested variables in Wix

Tags: wix

I am creating a WIX template for my projects to ensure a relatively standard layout.

I have defined a variable to reference the Main Application using `<?define MainApp="MyApp"?>` where MyApp is the name of the referenced project. I then use the MainApp variable to reference the project's properties in the .wxs and .wxi files.

However, I have an issue when referencing nested properties.

`$var.($(var.MainApp).ProjectName)` expands to "MyApp" without issue.

`$var.($(var.MainApp).ProjectDir)Resources\Main.ico` expands to `$var.(MyApp.ProjectDir)Resources\Main.ico`

`$var.($(var.MainApp).TargetPath)` expands to `$var.(ConsoleApplication1.TargetPath)`

etc...

My aim is to create a single definition for my main application, thus eliminating a search/replace, which I find clunky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found, nested preprocessor variables are not supported by the WiX toolset today.

Comment: Thanks Rob, at least now I know that it wasn't a syntax error. I will go back to find/replace. Any idea if/when nested preprocessor variables will be supported?

Comment: There may be a feature request open already. If not, one could be opened. Then someone just needs to implement the feature.

Comment: Feature request submitted to the project @ [https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/feature-requests/731/](https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/feature-requests/731/)